# Search an item based on a custom property

Tags: sharepoint, search, properties, sharepoint-2010

I started this task assuming it to be pretty trivial one. However, going to the depths i find that its either not that simple or may be i am using a wrong approach here. In my case i have a number of documents which are not in the same directory however, they have the same names/title. What i want is to carry out a site based search and resolve the document with least number of unrequired results.

So I decided to create a DocumentID (my custom ID) which is unique for each document and while storing the document using SPFile's Properties bucket I stored this new custom property DocumentIDalong with its value for every item. Now when i try searching out the document based on its DocumentID value i stored I dont get any results.

Reading the problem on internet gave me hint that i should be creating a Managed property to be able to search within custom properties. As required i did the same however, i could not find an appropriate crawled property for my custom property (DocumentID). Now unless i find the correct crawled propery which i believe isn't under my control i won't be able to utilize the power of Managed property search.

Anyone having a better idea or a solution to the point where i am stuck at? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Raghu

Comment: What is the query you are doing to do the 'search'? The problem could range from a trivial typo to a complete misconception.

Comment: Thanks Rich and Moron for prompt replies. 

Moron, 
I have created a ManagedProperty and trying to map that managed property to an appropriate crawl property. Thereafter I am using the Sharepoint OOTB search feature using the folloiwng syntax:- ManagedPropertyName:SearchText (e.g. DocumentID:238120-39ASDA-SD12321)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tag, it looks like you are using SharePoint 2010. If so, why not use the OOTB [Document ID Feature](http://blogs.technet.com/blairb/archive/2009/10/20/new-document-id-feature-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) in place of creating your own? The Document ID field will be part of the list item and should be available for search.

Comment: Rich, 
I should have mentioned this before as well. DocumentID is not the only one property I have as my custom property. There are a couple of other properties as well. And I am looking for a similar freedom on search for all of these properties.

Comment: What I could find at various internet sources is creating a new site/doclib column would make sure that my property is crawled successfully with ows_ appended in its name. That solves my problem but I am not satisfied with that solution. Here is the reason why. These 3 properties are specific to Documents types i.e. not all documents in a document library are supposed to have the 3 custom properties as there meta-data similarily not all Document libraries are bound to have documents which have these additonal custom meta-data.

Comment: So I was looking a way to attach these properties only to the required documents and also bring them under crawler's notice. Thereafter creating a managed property from the crawled equivalent of my custom properties and carrying out the OOTB sharepoint search using (ManagedPropertyName:SearchText) syntax.

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a separate Content Type for the documents that require your 3 custom fields.